# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have model contain class order in this action i create object from class order and fill data for it then serialize my object but throw exception

A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Order_5247E51E921C7E989617CBA5719815085C1A2851AB5D00E28EC0BE368D8ECD38'.

i use mvc 4 and linq

my controller action

```
    public ActionResult Posters(Order Obj)
    {
      Obj = new Order();
     //fill data of object Obj
     Session.Add("ObjOrder", Obj);
     String serializedResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((Order)Session["ObjOrder"]);
     ViewBag.Order = serializedResult;

     serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(page_OrderBostrat);
     ViewBag.BoxNum = serializedResult;
     var con = new { ViewBag.BoxNum, ViewBag.Order };
     page_OrderBostrat++;
     return Json(con, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

class order

```
    namespace MVCProject.Models
   {
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     public partial class Order
     {
         [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
         public Order()
         {
            this.IllustrativeFiles = new HashSet<IllustrativeFile>();
            this.Links = new HashSet<Link>();
            this.LogoColors = new HashSet<LogoColor>();
            this.LogoFiles = new HashSet<LogoFile>();
            this.ModelFiles = new HashSet<ModelFile>();
            this.Other = new HashSet<Other>();
            this.TatbeqatModelsImages = new HashSet<TatbeqatModelsImage>();
            this.ComputerPrograms = new HashSet<ComputerProgram>();
            this.InfographicModels = new HashSet<InfographicModel>();
            this.LogoModels = new HashSet<LogoModel>();
            this.PaintModels = new HashSet<PaintModel>();
            this.PosterModels = new HashSet<PosterModel>();
            this.PropagandaModels = new HashSet<PropagandaModel>();
            this.PublicationsModelsSizes = new HashSet<PublicationsModelsSize>();
            this.ResponsiveDesigns = new HashSet<ResponsiveDesign>();
            this.Structurals = new HashSet<Structural>();
        }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public string MainColor { get; set; }
    public string SecondColor { get; set; }
    public string ThirdColor { get; set; }
    public int PaintTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Language { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public int DesignType { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateAdd { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Seen { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string IpCountry { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsResponsiveDesign { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<IllustrativeFile> IllustrativeFiles { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<LogoColor> LogoColors { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<LogoFile> LogoFiles { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ModelFile> ModelFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderType OrderType { get; set; }
    public virtual PaintType PaintType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Other> Other { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TatbeqatModelsImage> TatbeqatModelsImages { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ComputerProgram> ComputerPrograms { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InfographicModel> InfographicModels { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<LogoModel> LogoModels { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PaintModel> PaintModels { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PosterModel> PosterModels { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PropagandaModel> PropagandaModels { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PublicationsModelsSize> PublicationsModelsSizes { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ResponsiveDesign> ResponsiveDesigns { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Structural> Structurals { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

how fix this problem ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in the many properties on the `Order` class there is found an object which itself references that same `Order` object, potentially one more more levels deep in the object graph.  This is likely happening in the `virtual` navigation properties.  To simplify, imagine an `Order` and a `Customer`:

```
class Order
{
    // properties describing the order

    // and the customer who placed the order...
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

class Customer
{
    // properties describing the customer

    // and the customer's orders...
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

How would this be serialized?  In order to serialize an `Order` you would also need to serialize its `Customer` property, and in order to serialize that property you would also need to serialize its `Orders` property, and in order to serialize those you would also need to serialize their `Customer` properties, and so on in an infinite recursion.

You're going to have to map out your object graph a little more carefully and make use of some attributes to tell the serializer what to ignore.  In the simplified example above, I might ignore the `Orders` property since I really only care about the aggregate root `Order` and its `Customer`:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Depending on the libraries you're using there could be a variety of serialization attributes from which to choose.  I believe `JsonIgnore` is part of the JSON.NET library.  But whatever you use, the main point here is to explicitly tell the serialization what to include/exclude when serializing an object so as to avoid an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks for you and i use String serializedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((Order)Session["ObjOrder"]);
instead of
String serializedResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((Order)Session["ObjOrder"]);

Comment: this answer makes no sense if it is generated by the entity framework. you cant modify every time you update the classes. there must be a better way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

The Json parser has to cycle every property of the deserialized object. One of those properties is an object that contains a reference to the initial object.

If your entities have navigation properties to other entities and it's possible to navigate from those entities back, then you have a circular reference. It will deserialize the object, navigate to a second object and deserialize it, then find the navigation to the original object and deserialize it, and so on. It's an infinite cycle.

You need to tell the deserializer to ignore the fields that have circular references using the annotation **[JsonIgnore]**

Answer (score 0):

I want to add on top of the already provided answer.

I've had this seemingly easy to solve problem in several scenarios. One was while feeding a Web API, and the other one was while trying to use jQuery Ajax (I was trying at the time get an entity from the database, and set its values in a Bootstrap modal form).

I solved this using [AutoMapper](https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki%20automapper). I made a [DTO](https://www.google.com/search?q=dto%20programming) (Data Transfer Object) from entities that were causing the recursion without adding the attached collections. AutoMapper (a convention-based object-object mapper) allowed me to select only the fields that I needed, avoiding any problematic ones.